# Connect to a RDS SQL Server instance from website deployed on AWS EC2 instance "Elasticbeanstalk"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created an RDS SQL Server instance and I am able to access from my local machine because of localhost.

But when I deploy the same website on elasticbeanstalk.com, it does not connect to the database because of some permission issues

Comment: The site having an SSL certificate should be irrelevant to the ability to connect to an RDS SQL server. What is the actual error message your server logs when trying to connect to the RDS server?

Comment: I can connect to DB using SQL server management studio or from a web application on localhost but when I deploy the same site on AWS I got the below error

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

Comment: It sounds like an AWS security group issue. Please focus on the networking configuration between the EC2 server and the RDS server. Not the networking connection between your web browser and the EC2 server (your focus on SSL certificates) which has no bearing in the issue you are encountering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved. I added an inbound rule for a security group that is used for RDS db instance.

Added port range from min to max and IP source to "0.0.0.0/0" for all TCP.

Comment: Do you recall how you did this? I am having the same issue. I understand what you did. I just can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

But it is not recommended to Added port range from min to max and IP source to "0.0.0.0/0" for all TCP as anyone can hit the server.